# How to apply sed if it contains one string but not another?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to convert this

```
url = ssh://git@git.company.com/project/repo.git
```

to

```
url = ssh://git@git.company.com/scm/project/repo.git
```

However, it's not a simple `sed` find and replace. I'd like it to only  apply the find and replace if the string starts with `\turl` and doesn't already contain `scm`.

I have the beginning portion where it will only replace lines containing `\turl`

```
cat .git/config | sed "/\turl/ s=\.com\/=\.com\/scm\/=g"
```

but to make this idempotent, I'm having trouble checking if it contains the `scm` string already. Otherwise if I keep running the command with seds `-i` then it will keep adding `scm`.

Answer (score 6):

In sed, this should work:

```
sed '/url/ { /scm/! s=\.com/=\.com/scm/=g }'
```

You can negate an andress by adding a `!` after it, and you can apply an address regex to another by using blocks.

Or maybe, if `scm` only afer `.com/` should be checked for:

```
sed '/url/ { \=\.com/scm/= ! s=\.com/=\.com/scm/=g }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
! grep -q '/scm/' .git/config && sed "/\turl/ s=\.com\/=\.com\/scm\/=g" .git/config
```

or

```
grep -q '/scm/' .git/config || sed "/\turl/ s=\.com\/=\.com\/scm\/=g" .git/config
```

If the file doesn't contain `/scm/`, then sed ...